# how to solve this error: "'TreeEnsemble' object has no attribute 'model_output'"

Tags: python, numpy, joblib, shap, bz2

'''
features = [gender, SeniorCitizen, Partner, Dependents, Tenure, PhoneService, MultipleLines, OnlineSecurity, OnlineBackup,
DeviceProtection, TechSupport, StreamingTV, StreamingMovies, PaperlessBilling, MonthlyCharges, TotalCharges,
InternetService_Fiberoptic, InternetService_No, Contract_Oneyear,Contract_Twoyear,
PaymentMethod_CreditCard, PaymentMethod_ElectronicCheck, PaymentMethod_MailedCheck]
final_features = [np.array(features)]

```
prediction = model.predict_proba(final_features)

output = prediction[0,1]

# Shap Values
explainer = joblib.load(filename="explainer.bz2")
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(np.array(final_features))
shap_img = io.BytesIO()
shap.force_plot(explainer.expected_value[1], shap_values[1], columns, matplotlib = True, show = False).savefig(shap_img, bbox_inches="tight", format = 'png')
shap_img.seek(0)
shap_url = base64.b64encode(shap_img.getvalue()).decode()
```

The error is coming about tree ensemble when we try to run the python file.The error says: 'TreeEnsemble' object has no attribute 'model_output'. Please help to correct this error
the traceback is :
File "C:\Users\utrej\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1836, in **call**
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "C:\Users\utrej\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
File "C:\Users\utrej\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "C:\Users\utrej\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\flask_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
raise value
File "C:\Users\utrej\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "C:\Users\utrej\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "C:\Users\utrej\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "C:\Users\utrej\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\flask_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
raise value
File "C:\Users\utrej\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "C:\Users\utrej\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functionsrule.endpoint
File "C:\Users\utrej\Desktop####\product dev lab\Customer-Survival-Analysis-and-Churn-Prediction-master\app.py", line 118, in predict
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(np.array(final_features))
File "C:\Users\utrej\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\shap\explainers\tree.py", line 298, in shap_values
if self.model.model_output == "log_loss":

Comment: Correct the formatting, and provide full traceback.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please [reprex]